# In R perform k means clustering with k=3 and euclidean distance a 100 different times

Tags: clustering, k-means, euclidean

I would like to perform k mean clustering with k=3 and the Euclidean distance a 100 different time.

But it only gives me 2 iterations, how do i do a loop so it give me 100.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lapply(1:100, function(i) kmeans(ir, 3))
```

will give you a list of 100 repeats of that line of code.

Comment: Thank you. I have tried it but this just repeats the same loop 100 times. I need 100 different times. Any ideas?